# set data from API as variable - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so i'm currently getting an array of data from a mock api, I'm trying to put that data into an object that I've created and then render it on the screen. Currently I've got as far as getting the data from the API but when I try to put the data into the variable and print the result, it doesn't work, it does however work when I print the data inside of the function that calls the data (shown below). It also calls the Future function (getUserFeed) on init of the page (or state, I'm not sure) - This is the current code:

```
class SocialPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String argument;
  const SocialPage({Key key, this.argument}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SocialPageState createState() => _SocialPageState(argument);
}

  Future getUserFeed() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      'https://cartalkio-mock-api.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/textfeed.json');

  print(response.statusCode);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class _SocialPageState extends State<SocialPage> {
  String argument;
  _SocialPageState(this.argument);
  Future feedData;

  setFeedData() {
    setState(() {
      feedData = getUserFeed();
    });
  }

  checkFeedData() {
    print(feedData);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: (FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, SectionSelectRoute, arguments: argument);
      })),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: setFeedData,
              child: (Text('Set data')),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: checkFeedData,
              child: (Text('Check data')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what is returned when I call the 'checkFeedData' function:

```
Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

[EDIT]

Based on the answer provided by P4yam, this is what its been changed to:

```
Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getUserFeed() async {
  final response = await http.get(
      'https://cartalkio-mock-api.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/textfeed.json');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(json.decode(response.body));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class _SocialPageState extends State<SocialPage> {
  String argument;
  _SocialPageState(this.argument);
  Map<String,dynamic> feedData;

 setFeedData() async{
    feedData = await getUserFeed();
  }

  checkFeedData() {
    print(feedData);
  }
```

Buttons calling the functions

```
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: setFeedData,
          child: (Text('Set data')),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: checkFeedData,
          child: (Text('Check data')),
        ),
```

The getUserFeed function prints the actual data that comes from the API but when I call the checkFeedData function, it prints null.

[EDIT 2]

Function

```
  setFeedData() async{
    feedData = await getUserFeed();
    print('-----------'); // It's not running this print function 
    print(feedData); // Dont think its running this function
  }
```

Console

```
I/flutter ( 6245): 200
I/flutter ( 6245): [{id: 2, photoUrl: https://cartalkio-image-storage-dev.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/o85DvOaTXXE.jpg, description: Magna duis consectetur sit ut commodo non eiusmod., dateAdded: 0001-01-01T00:00:00, isMain: false, publicId: null, isImage: true, mainImage: https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/76.jpg, userId: 9, likers: null, username: Larsen, thumbnail: null, likes: 0}, {id: 4, photoUrl: https://cartalkio-image-storage-dev.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/lXR833PRh3g.jpg, description: Magna duis consectetur sit ut commodo non eiusmod., dateAdded: 0001-01-01T00:00:00, isMain: false, publicId: null, isImage: true, mainImage: https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/4.jpg, userId: 8, likers: null, username: Lloyd, thumbnail: null, likes: 0}, {id: 6, photoUrl: https://cartalkio-image-storage-dev.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/geTFl8b0m9M.jpg, description: Magna duis consectetur sit ut commodo non eiusmod., dateAdded: 0001-01-01T00:00:00, isMain: false, publicId: null, isImage: true, mainImage: https://randomuser.me/api/port
E/flutter ( 6245): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, dynamic>>'
E/flutter ( 6245): #0      getUserFeed (package:TCS/social.dart:29:5)
E/flutter ( 6245): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6245): #1      _SocialPageState.setFeedData (package:TCS/social.dart:48:22)
E/flutter ( 6245): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
E/flutter ( 6245): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter ( 6245): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 6245): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
E/flutter ( 6245): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
E/flutter ( 6245): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7)
E/flutter ( 6245): #8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
E/flutter ( 6245): #9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 6245): #10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter ( 6245): #11     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 6245): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter ( 6245): #13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter ( 6245): #14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 6245): #15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 6245): #16     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 6245): #17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 6245): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 6245): #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1196:13)
E/flutter ( 6245): #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter ( 6245): #21     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter ( 6245): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)
E/flutter ( 6245): #23     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)
E/flutter ( 6245):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change `feedData` to this:

```
List<dynamic> feedData;
```

then change `Future getUserFeed()` to :

```
Future<List<dynamic>> getUserFeed(){
...
```

and also change `setFeedData` to :

```
  setFeedData() async{
      feedData = await getUserFeed();
  }
```

Comment: I've done this, but when I call 'checkFeedData', it just returns null. I've edited the question to show more information

Comment: @chumberjosh what happens when inside `setFeedData` you call `print(feedData);` after the await ?

Comment: it prints a whole load of stuff, but from what I can tell it doesn't actually run that print function, I've updated the question so you can see whats being printed

Comment: @chumberjosh I edited the answer, the api returns a json array instead of json object so i think this time it will work.